# Flutter Image overlay for Google Maps Marker

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, maps

I want to show a user image on the google map marker but I don't know how to do it?

Check the result I want here:

Marker Image:

[image]

The Result I want:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Repo:
https://github.com/amorenew/Flutter_avatar_maps

I used this library:

```
  image: ^2.1.4
```

My main.dart

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Images;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

  Future<List<int>> makeReceiptImage() async {
    // load avatar image
    ByteData imageData = await rootBundle.load('assets/av.png');
    List<int> bytes = Uint8List.view(imageData.buffer);
    var avatarImage = Images.decodeImage(bytes);

    //load marker image 
    imageData = await rootBundle.load('assets/ma.png');
    bytes = Uint8List.view(imageData.buffer);
    var markerImage = Images.decodeImage(bytes);

    //resize the avatar image to fit inside the marker image
    avatarImage = Images.copyResize(avatarImage,
        width: markerImage.width ~/ 1.1, height: markerImage.height ~/ 1.4);


    var radius = 90;
    int originX = avatarImage.width ~/ 2, originY = avatarImage.height ~/ 2;

    //draw the avatar image cropped as a circle inside the marker image
    for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
      for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
        if (x * x + y * y <= radius * radius)
          markerImage.setPixelSafe(originX + x+8, originY + y+10,
              avatarImage.getPixelSafe(originX + x, originY + y));


    return Images.encodePng(markerImage);
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<int> myImage;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    widget.makeReceiptImage().then((List<int> image) {
      setState(() {
        myImage = image;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade100,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            myImage == null ? Text('fdassd') : Image.memory(myImage),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use local asset its an easy way to do that like @CopsOnRoad said, but, if you will load from network i will recommend this by the moment [Flutter map inspire in Leaflet](https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map) i have been using for a while know if work pretty fine.

Comment: I checked it but my main question is about image overlay on another image

Comment: you can use a widget in that map so you can create the overlay with a Stack and add the overlays that you need :D

Comment: i'm not using google maps, because of that (not supported). I send you the link to another map plugin call flutter_map this one allow the widget and you can use any widget that you want in the marker. click the link i put in my post :D

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can't really use `Widget` for `Marker`, but here is what you can try, (haven't tested it personally)

```
var image = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
  ImageConfiguration(),
  "assets/images/your_image.jpg",
);

Marker marker = Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId("id"),
  icon: image,
);
```

Comment: this will show the image instead of the marker.
My question is for adding an image on top of another image then using it as a marker

Comment: That's what I was saying, you can't use it like that as of now.

Comment: If I don't find a solution for overlay image then I should open an issue.

Comment: Follow the question here I will open an issue and I am sure the flutter team has a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest some solution, there is some nice library https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images ,
so generally when you run over yours markers array you merge 2 images or more to base 64. here is code snippet:

```
getMarkerImage(elementMarker, fullArray) {
    mergeImages([
      { src: './assets/img/markers/map-marker64.png', x: 0, y: 0 },
      { src: elementMarker.info.image || './assets/img/markers/markerIcon42.png', x: 11, y: 4 },
    ])
      .then(imgData => {
        console.log(imgData);
        this.markersImages.push(imgData);
        if (this.markersImages.length === this.controllersfullArray - 4) {
          fullArray.forEach((element, i) => {
            this.markers.push({
              lat: element.info.location.latitude,
              lng: element.info.location.longitude,
              controllerInfo: element.info,
              icon: {
                url: this.markersImages[i],
                labelOrigin: { x: 32, y: -10 },
                scaledSize: {
                  width: 64,
                  height: 64
                }
              },
              controllerStaus: element.status,
              label: {
                text: element.info.siteName,
                color: "#ED2C2C",
                fontWeight: "500",
                fontSize: "14px"
              }
            });
            console.log(this.markers);
          });
        }
      });
    // return (mergeImages({ src: './assets/img/markers/map-marker64.png', x: 0, y: 0 },
  }
```

but be aware you need to use all images that are on the same Domain. because if  not toDataUrl will throw an error of cross-origin